# How to get SFML's error message to Cython?

Tags: python, c++, cython, sfml, cythonize

I'm trying to wrap SFML's error stream to retrieve last error message into Python space.

Here is how SFML declares it's error stream ([see source](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/include/SFML/System/Err.hpp)):

```
namespace sf {
    std::ostream& err();
}
```

SFML says, that you can redirect the above stream into your buffer (in the example into a file, but I want to convert it to a string eventually):

```
// Redirect to a file
std::ofstream file("sfml-log.txt");
std::streambuf* previous = sf::err().rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
```

My .pxd file with some simplistic wrappers:

```
cdef extern from '<sstream>' namespace 'std' nogil:
    cppclass stringbuf:
        stringbuf() except +

cdef extern from '<iostream>' namespace 'std' nogil:
    cppclass ostream:
        stringbuf* rdbuf(stringbuf*)

cdef extern from 'SFML/System.hpp' namespace 'sf' nogil:
    ostream cerr 'sf::err'
```

And my .pyx module:

```
cdef void set_error_handler(stringbuf& buffer):
    cerr.rdbuf(&buffer)

cdef object get_last_error():
    error = error_buffer.str()
    error_buffer.str('')
    return error

cdef stringbuf error_buffer
set_error_handler(error_buffer)
```

Also do I'm converting `stringbuf` with the error message into a Python string properly in the `get_last_error()` function?

### Update

I've managed to compile my Cython code. I've added parentheses here:

```
cdef extern from 'SFML/System.hpp' namespace 'sf' nogil:
    ostream cerr 'sf::err()'  # Added ()
```

But still I can't retrieve an error reported by SFML to appear in my `stringbuf error_buffer` when calling `get_last_error()` defined above (return value is an empty string).

Comment: stringbuf has an str() method that will return a copy of the underlying string. Note you'll need to clear the buffet after reading it, otherwise messages will accumulate.

Comment: @spectras Thanks for this! Updated question.